# Split One Column To Tow Column

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have `CurrentCurve Change <1> --> <4>` value in column `text`.

I want split `text` to `from` and `to` column.

```
from | to
__________
1    | 4
```

I write this query

```
select 
  REGEXP_replace( curve.text,'CurrentCurve Change <|> --> <[0-9]>') as from,
  REGEXP_replace( curve.text,'CurrentCurve Change <[0-9]> --> <|>') as to,
from mytable
```

There is better way for do it.

Comment: Do you want to just extract two numbers from any string, or the two numbers from only the `CurrentCurve Change <digits> --> <digits>` string?

Answer (score 4):

Actually `REGEXP_SUBSTR` would probably be more useful here:

```
SELECT
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '\d+', 1, 1) AS "from",
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '\d+', 1, 2) AS "to"
FROM mytable;
```

### Demo

Note: `FROM` is a reserved Oracle/SQL keyword, and you should not be using it for your table and column names.  I also learned here to `TO` also appears to be a reserved keyword.  I had to place both your aliases in double quotes to get my demo to run.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you want a number between `<` and `>`.

You can use the following `REGEXP_SUBSTR` which only fetches the number between `<` and `>` and ignore all other digits(example 2 with other digits in your input string):

```
SQL> -- Example 1
SQL> SELECT
  2      REGEXP_SUBSTR('CurrentCurve Change <1> --> <4>', '<(\d+)>', 1, 1, null, 1 ) AS "from",
  3      REGEXP_SUBSTR('CurrentCurve Change <1> --> <4>', '<(\d+)>', 1, 2, null, 1 ) AS "to"
  4  FROM dual;

from to
---- --
1    4

SQL>
SQL> -- Example 2
SQL> SELECT
  2      REGEXP_SUBSTR('CurrentCurve 2 Change <1> --> <4>', '<(\d+)>', 1, 1, null, 1 ) AS "from",
  3      REGEXP_SUBSTR('CurrentCurve 2 Change <1> --> <4>', '<(\d+)>', 1, 2, null, 1 ) AS "to"
  4  FROM dual;

from to
---- --
1    4

SQL>
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c2b6be5cc3e46f4bde0e8221a631f044)**

Cheers!!